# How can I write the code for a this.label.Click to trigger two events?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, mouseclick-event

Here's my code

```
private void ScoreOnes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll_Click;
        this.ScoreOnes.Click -= null;

    }
```

ScoreOnes is a label, and Roll is a label. I want to trigger the Roll_Click, and make ScoreOnes unclickable, both when ScoreOnes is clicked at the SAME TIME. If I do the way I have written the code, I have to click twice to make ScoreOnes unclickable. If I do it this way:

```
private void ScoreOnes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ScoreOnes.Click -= null;
        this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll_Click;

    }
```

ScoreOnes never becomes unclickable ..... Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't triggering `Roll_Click`. It's hooking up the event listener so that *next time* `ScoreOnes` is clicked, `Roll_Click` will be invoked.

As for unclickable, do you mean disabled? Or it just does nothing?

If you want it to just do nothing when it's clicked in, you can write something like this:

```
bool scoreOnesDisabled;
private void ScoreOnes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (scoreOnesDisabled)
        return;

    this.Roll_Click(sender, e);
    scoreOnesDisabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I had this in mind too! I just wanted to know if there's a way in c# to invoke more than one events at the same time. Much thanks again!

Comment: @HaroonIftikhar yes you can. In your form constructor after the InitializeComponent() call,   Or in form_load   add as many handlers as you want.   this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll_Click;    this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll2_Click;      this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll3_Click;

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void ScoreOnes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roll_Click(); //this fires the Roll_Click method
    this.ScoreOnes.Enabled = False; // this makes ScoreOnes unclickable

}
```

Comment: Um, actually cannot call Roll_Click() that way, needs to be a this. instance. But yes the enabled part does do the same job! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Wire up Roll_Click event handler in form load

```
void frmQmsQuote_Edit_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.ScoreOnes.Click += this.Roll_Click;
}
```

In ScoreOnes_Click event handler detach self so it wont fire again

```
private void ScoreOnes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ScoreOnes.Click -= ScoreOnes_Click;
}
```

Or use the disable method that Jim VanPetten has suggested in the other answer.